# Null Pointer Exception Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nullpointerexception

I am trying to use AWS S3 SDK. My project structure is divided modules for better modularity.

I have 4 files

```
+-- S3Application.java
+-- S3InterfaceImpl.java
+-- S3Config.java
+-- S3CreateBucketClient.java\
```

Here are the code for each of the aforementioned files:

```
public class S3Application{

private static S3InterfaceImpl S3InterfaceImpl;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try {
            System.out.println("Reached");
            S3InterfaceImpl.createBucket("hello123");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception");
        }

    }
}
```

I have `S3InterfaceImpl` with `createBucket` method which then calls `s3CreateBucketClient.createBucket`

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class S3InterfaceImpl implements S3Interface {

    private Logger log;

    private S3CreateBucketClient s3CreateBucketClient;


    @Override
    public void createBucket(String bucketName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            System.out.println("Reached");
            s3CreateBucketClient.createBucket(bucketName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception while creating bucket {}", bucketName, e);
            //throw new TechnicalException(ErrorCode.S3_PROCESSING_FAILED, e);
        }

    }
}
```

Here I have `S3Config` to configure my access keys

```
public class S3Config {

    private static final AWSCredentials credentials;
    static {
        //put your accesskey and secretkey here
        credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
                "<access-key>",
                "<secret-key>");
    };
    public AmazonS3 createS3Client() {

            AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                    .standard()
                    .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://192.168.44.225:9000","us-east-1"))
                    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                    .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(false)
                    .build();

        return s3Client;
    }

}
```

Here I have `S3CreateBucketClient` with AWS SDK methods.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class S3CreateBucketClient {

    private Logger log;

    private S3Config S3Config = new S3Config();
    private final AmazonS3 s3Client = S3Config.createS3Client();

    public void createBucket(String bucketName) {
        boolean bucketExist = s3Client.doesBucketExistV2(bucketName);
        log.info("Bucket with name {} exist {}", bucketName, bucketExist);
        if(!bucketExist) {
            Bucket bucket = s3Client.createBucket(bucketName);
            if(bucket == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create bucket with name " + bucketName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException` at `S3InterfaceImpl.createBucket("hello123");` in `S3Application`

Comment: Are you sure `new BasicAWSCredentials()` has been invoked by the time that line is executed?

Comment: What changes do I make to the code to reflect that?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be nothing related to AWS or S3, and is an issue with your OOP code. You have to assign an instance of an object to a variable that is declared with a class type before you try to access a member of that variable/object.

In S3Application you are never instantiating the S3InterfaceImpl property in your class with an instance of S3InterfaceImpl before you call the create function. So if you debug the line of code that is failing and inspects the S3InterfaceImpl  variable, you should see it has a NULL value.  When you try to access any member on a variable with a value of NULL, you get a NullPointerException.

Somewhere you need S3InterfaceImpl = new S3InterfaceImpl() or you need to use DI to inject one.